# Unresolved external symbol WppAutoLogTrace when building a driver with Dmf Framework

Tags: driver, windows-wpp

I'm trying to build a driver with Microsoft Dmf Framework https://github.com/microsoft/DMF

I builded Dmf from the provided sln file in this repository. It results in DmfK.lib (I build a kernel mode driver), then I add this lib to my driver project.

But I have 27 times the same linker error "unresolved external symbol WppAutoLogTrace" from different functions of this lib, ie:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol WppAutoLogTrace referenced in function "long __cdecl HashTable_ContextInitialize(struct DMFMODULE__ *)" (?HashTable_ContextInitialize@@YAJPEAUDMFMODULE__@@@Z)   Main (Main\Main)    C:\Data\Development\MyDriver\Source\Main\DmfK.lib(Dmf_HashTable.obj)
```

I found no relevant information about this function over the internet, I can't figure out which other lib to include. Is this a problem with a missing lib or an issue with the DmfK.lib build ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I totally know what an unresolved symbol is and how to fix it in most cases. But in this case I think I missed something about Dmf Framework and its mysterious "WppAutoLogTrace" function. I can't find the lib in which it is supposed to be implemented ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

WppAutoLogTrace is implemented in WppRecorder.lib